# how can i use a URI in a vcf file

Tags: vcf-vcard

I am looking to have a vCard that can be downloaded from a website. For a photo: is there a way to reference a URI instead of hardcoding an inline base64 version of the photo.

The content in the image below works however I am hoping to have the vcard update the contact image if I was to change it.

- i.e. I would update the content of https://...SomePictureInBase64.txt on my server and the user's device would see an updated contact photo. Similar to how a profile picture on linkedin is updated when a user searches for you.

[image]

Comment: Hi, have you tried especifying the PHOTO line like this? 
"PHOTO;JPEG:http://example.com/photo.jpg"

Comment: take a look here:  https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6350.html#section-6.2.4